# font-size won't apply to primary text in list tile

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Recently i'm learning gluon mobile, and found that the javafx css functioned wired.

Following the tutorial of "[Comments](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/comments/)", I made a view called "CommentsView", when 
I tried to change the font size of primary text and secondary text in comment list tile, it would not take any effect.

Can you explain why the `-fx-font-size` for the texts in list tile not functioned as expected ? thank you very much .

This is my code:

```
// CommentsPresenter.java
import com.freedom.demo.Comments;
import com.freedom.demo.model.Comment;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.FloatingActionButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CommentsPresenter {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommentsPresenter.class.getName());

    @FXML
    private View comments;

    @FXML
    private ListView commentView;

    public void initialize() {
        comments.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().getDrawer().open()));
                appBar.setTitleText("Comments");

                Swatch.ORANGE.assignTo(comments.getScene());
            }
        });
        final FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(MaterialDesignIcon.ADD.text,
                e -> MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(Comments.EDITION_VIEW));
        floatingActionButton.showOn(comments);

        commentView.setCellFactory(p -> new CommentListCell());
        commentView.setPlaceholder(new Label("There are no comments"));
        commentView.getItems().add(new Comment("wtx", "hello world!中国"));
    }

    @FXML
    void buttonClick() {
    }

}
// CommentListCell.java
import com.freedom.demo.model.Comment;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ListTile;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CommentListCell extends ListCell<Comment>{
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommentListCell.class.getName());

    private final ListTile tile = new ListTile();

    private Comment comment;
    {
        tile.getStyleClass().add("comment-list");
    }

    {
        final Button button = MaterialDesignIcon.DELETE.button();
        tile.setSecondaryGraphic(new VBox(button));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Comment item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        comment = item;
        if (!empty && item != null) {
            tile.textProperty().setAll(item.getAuthor(), item.getContent(), item.getDateStr());
            setGraphic(tile);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my css and html:

```
.view {
}
.comment-list {
    -fx-background-color: -primary-swatch-50;
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-swatch-700;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 10 0;
}
.comment-list .primary-text {
    -fx-font-size: 30;
    -fx-padding: 10 0 10 0;
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-swatch-900;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.comment-list .secondary-text{
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
.button.icon-toggle {
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-swatch-900;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<View fx:id="comments" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" stylesheets="@comments.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.freedom.demo.views.CommentsPresenter">
   <center>
      <ListView fx:id="commentView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</View>
```

After lunched **iphone5S** simulator, the view showed as flowing:
[image]

ps: this is my dependency tree:

```
+--- com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0
|    +--- com.gluonhq:connect:1.4.4
|    |    \--- org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4
|    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-cloudlink-client:4.4.7
|    |    +--- com.gluonhq:connect:1.4.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-device:3.6.0
|    |    |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.6.0 -> 3.8.0
|    |    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-in-app-billing:3.6.0
|    |    |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.6.0 -> 3.8.0
|    |    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-push-notifications:3.6.0
|    |    |    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.6.0 -> 3.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-runtime-args:3.6.0
|    |    |         \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.6.0 -> 3.8.0
|    |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-storage:3.6.0 -> 3.8.0
|    |         \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.8.0
|    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-glisten-connect-view:5.0.0
|    |    +--- com.gluonhq:charm-cloudlink-client:4.4.7 (*)
|    |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:5.0.0
|    |         +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display:3.8.0
|    |         |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.8.0
|    |         +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-lifecycle:3.8.0
|    |         |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.8.0
|    |         +--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-statusbar:3.8.0
|    |         |    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-core:3.8.0
|    |         \--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-storage:3.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:5.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.guava:guava:26.0 FAILED
+--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display:3.8.0 (*)
+--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-lifecycle:3.8.0 (*)
+--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-statusbar:3.8.0 (*)
+--- com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-storage:3.8.0 (*)
\--- com.gluonhq:robovm-cocoatouch:2.3.1-ios11
     \--- com.gluonhq:robovm-objc:2.3.1-ios11
```

Comment: I have fix the problem by replacing the list tile in `CommentListCell` by a self-designed BorderPane, which filled by the three labels. In my opinion, `ListTile` should do the similar thing, however, still can't figure out where i went wrong ……

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of being able to run on Desktop before you test on mobile is that you can use [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to check issues like the one you are posting in advance.

If you run your app and launch Scenic View you will see:

[image: ScenicView]

Notice that the `ListTile` control has a `VBox`, with style class `text-box`, that serves as a container for the labels `primary-text`, `secondary-text`.

So all you need to add in your css is this relation:

```
.comment-list > .text-box > .primary-text {
    -fx-font-size: 30;
    -fx-padding: 10 0 10 0;
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-swatch-900;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.comment-list > .text-box > .secondary-text{
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Now you can test again your app:

[image]

Comment: SceneView is a great tool, thank you jose ! Still my question is since the background color can applied to the right elements, why font-size can't ?